# Pinterest API - 403 error when requesting access token on Dreamhost server

Tags: php, api, oauth, pinterest

I'm using [this php wrapper](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP), successfully getting a code from pinterest using the link generated according to the docs:

```
$loginurl = $pinterest->auth->getLoginUrl($callback_url, array('read_public'));
```

Then when I run this:

```
$token = $pinterest->auth->getOAuthToken($_GET['code']);
```

It works fine on my local server, but when I try to run it on our Dreamhost server, I get:

```
Pinterest error (code: 403) with message: Forbidden
```

I looked through the [error documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/#oauth-errors) Pinterest supplies, but I can't find anything relating to 403 errors when retrieving oauth tokens.

The only two places I've seen mention of 403 errors when requesting oauth tokens from Pinterest's API have concluded that [Pinterest is blocking the ips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867047/pinterest-api-returning-403-on-ec2-instance) or [the user agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287840/pinterest-denying-access-from-google-app-engine-403).

I've tried manually overriding the user agent string to no avail.

I've tried contacting Pinterest to find out if there is anything I'm missing and they directed me here.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Sadly no, all of my communications with Pinterest have ended in them telling me that they're working on it and they'll get back to me, it's been like 3 months now since I last communicated with them. I can't even manually get information from Pinterest via requesting the Pinterest rss feed with curl.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Dreamhost server is using an HTTPS URL e.g. is using TLS. That could be the reason why you get a 403.